# Face recognition using Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, face-recognition, camera, face-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

Does Kinect work with gscam, which is mentioned in the following link

[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/face_recognition#)

Thanks in advance.
Arjun

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39540/face-recognition-using-kinect/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, the [Kinect](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect) has its own special driver. However, you should be able run that tutorial as written, but just skip step 2, and adjust your image topics to something published by the Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2